# Problems with pointer into structure

Tags: c

The memory has not been freeded
Please some help with this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct paramint
{
   short  val;
   char   name[150 + 1];
}tParamint;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    tParamint *e;

    e=(tParamint*)malloc(2*sizeof(tParamint));
    e[1].val=12;
    e[2].val=13;

    printf("e[1].val=[%d]\n", e[1].val);
    printf("e[2].val=[%d]\n", e[2].val);
    free(e);
    printf("e[1].val=[%d]\n", e[1].val);
    printf("e[2].val=[%d]\n", e[2].val);

    return 0;
}
```

Initial value:
e[1].val=[12]
e[2].val=[13]

After free
e[1].val=[12]
e[2].val=[13]

Comment: What is the problem? Please explain it first. There’s only undefined behavior which can result in anything happening.

Comment: after free(e) there woud be feeded memory space to e[1],val and e[2].val...try to run the code and validate the results

Comment: Yes the memory is freed. It doesn’t mean the memory pointed to would necessarily change. It’s *undefined behavior* to use freed memory. Anything can happen. Including the same data being there when you erroneously read it. It can’t be validated because it’s undefined.

Comment: Your accessing outside the bounds of your array.  `e` points to a memory segment containing two `tParamint`s, but you are addressing `e[2]`, which would be the third element.  That is problematic.

Comment: Arrays in C are 0-indexed, simple as that. You write out of bounds and corrupt the memory.

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

There are two points

> 1. A block of memory previously allocated by a call to malloc, calloc or realloc is deallocated, making it available again for further allocations.
> 2. Notice that this function does not change the value of ptr itself, hence it still points to the same (now invalid) location.

So the memory you just freed, are not deallocated immediately, it just marked as re-allocatable and your `ptr` is pointing to those invalid location. So it's a good idea to de-referencing the ptr to `null` just after freeing the `ptr`.

By de-referencing the `ptr` to `null` after you also make sure that, you are not freeing the same memory more than once.

Comment: The problem here is simply that the OP doesn't understand how arrays work in C. `e[2].val=13;` causing heap corruption.

Comment: Yes, that is another issue, because OP is using 1 indexed to specify the item's in the array. But the same problem will persist in case OP using 0 indexing (which is right). Directly from the question "The memory has not been freeded Please some help with this problem".